# Struggle with LSTM and RNN using Keras

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, google-colaboratory

I'm working on a speech recognition problem running on Colab using LSTM. The audio files were converted into spectrograms and then normalized. There are 6840 spectrograms in total and the shape of each one is (288, 864, 4). 
I already tried a few examples with RNN and CNN and they worked, but when I try an example using a LSTM I get shape errors, every time either there is one more or one less dimension than expected. Here are some of these cases :

```
rnn = keras.Sequential()
rnn.add(keras.layers.SimpleRNN(500, input_shape = (864, 4)))
rnn.add(keras.layers.LSTM(500, return_sequences = True))
rnn.add(keras.layers.Dropout(0.2))
rnn.add(keras.layers.LSTM(500, return_sequences = True))
rnn.add(keras.layers.Dropout(0.2))
rnn.add(keras.layers.LSTM(500, return_sequences = True))
rnn.add(keras.layers.Dropout(0.2))
rnn.add(keras.layers.Dense(212, activation = 'softmax'))
rnn.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy',metrics = ['accuracy'])
rnn.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs = 5, validation_data=(X_test, y_test))
scores = rnn.evaluate(X_test, y_test, verbose=1)
print('Test loss:', scores[0])
print('Test accuracy:', '%.2f' % (scores[1] * 100), '%')
```

The following error is raised on the first LSTM layer : `ValueError: Input 0 of layer lstm_54 is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2. Full shape received: [None, 500]`

If I remove the SimpleRNN line and feed the input directly to the first LSTM like this 
`rnn.add(keras.layers.LSTM(500, return_sequences = True, input_shape = (288, 864, 4)))`
I get : `ValueError: Input 0 of layer lstm_56 is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=4. Full shape received: [None, 288, 864, 4]`

I tried reshaping the images to (4, 288 * 864) and got the same error when trying to use the RNN layer, but with just the LSTM I got `InvalidArgumentError: Incompatible shapes: [32] vs. [32,4]`.
No idea where the 32 came from, though.

One last thing, not really an issue but more of a request, is there any library that can resize images the simple way? 288x864 is too big for Colab, so I'll have to do it eventually to be able to load all 6840 images and feed it to the neural network. Right now I'm just using 100 samples to test.

Feel free to leave suggestions about other methods, cabalistic number of nodes/layers or anything like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LSTM input is 3 dimensions [n_samples, n_timesteps, n_features], so your first line also need to enable return sequences:

```
rnn.add(keras.layers.SimpleRNN(500, return_sequences = True, input_shape = (864, 4)))
```

Next, your Dense layer will complain from wrong input size, so you want to remove return_sequence on the last LSTM network:

```
rnn.add(keras.layers.LSTM(500))
```

If you still want to keep the `return_sequences = True` on the last LSTM layer, you might want to wrap the Dense layer in a TimeDistributed.

I tried it on the following input and they seems to work

```
X_train = np.random.rand(100, 864, 4)
y_train = np.random.rand(100, 1)
```

The PIL from pillow package has plenty of image manipulation methods.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. I still got this error: `ValueError: Error when checking input: expected simple_rnn_12_input to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (80, 288, 864, 4)`. And for your X_train you omitted the first dimension, so it should be `X_train = np.random.rand(100, 288, 864, 4)`

Comment: But it worked for the reshaped array, thank you very much :)